Background color of expo tabs stay gray
I use expo to create an android app.
I have a _layout.tsx file.
Inside it, I use the Tabs from expo-router to set a navbar at the bottom.
Above the tabs, I have a View with a red background.
import '../../global.css';
import HeaderDefault from '@/components/header/default';
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { UINotificationToast } from '@/components/ui/notification/Toast';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function ContextLayout() {

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FF0000' /* Red background */ }}
      >
        <Tabs
          screenOptions={{
            header: ({ route }) => <HeaderDefault alignLeft={true} />,
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#FBFFFE',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tabs.Screen name='dashboard' />
        </Tabs>
      </View>
      <UINotificationToast />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

The result is this:

If I comment the tabs section, I got the expected:

I have searched in every documentation and topic I have no a clue from what this color come from.
And I do not find a way to change the background color of the Tabs.

try this:

separate view above tabs so you have precise control over layout

<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.redBackground} />
   <View style={styles.tabsContainer}>
      <Tabs
         screenOptions={{
         header: ({ route }) => <HeaderDefault alignLeft={true} />,
         tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FBFFFE',
              },
            }}
          >
            <Tabs.Screen name="dashboard" />
     </Tabs>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  redBackground: {
    height: 50, // Adjust height as needed
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});



Thanks for your response. If I do this I have the same result as the screen 1, with 50px above the header in red.
But, what I want is to change this gray color of the content.
I can do it using Stack, but not the Tabs...

Find it!
Inside each child Tabs.Screen we can add a sceneStyle, and it seems that the scene is the content.


import '../../global.css';
import HeaderDefault from '@/components/header/default';
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { UINotificationToast } from '@/components/ui/notification/Toast';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function ContextLayout() {

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FF0000' /* Red background */ }}
      >
        <Tabs
          screenOptions={{
            header: ({ route }) => <HeaderDefault alignLeft={true} />,
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#FBFFFE',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tabs.Screen 
            name='dashboard' 
            options={{
              sceneStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'red', // This what you want
              },
            }}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </View>
      <UINotificationToast />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}




